# Why ulimit returns different results through java Runtime.exec()

Tags: java, bash, unix

why the 'ulimit -a' returns differently through Runtime.exec() from running it straight under bash, thanks for any pointers.

Java: 
open files (-n) 65536

bash-3.00$ ulimit -a:
open files (-n) 256

```
public class TestUlimit {
    public TestUlimit() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = runTime.exec(new String[] { "bash", "-c", "ulimit -a" });
            InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            System.out.println("Result of Process p = runTime.exec(new String[]     { \"bash\", \"-c\", \"ulimit -a\" });");
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
            }
            p.waitFor();

            p = runTime.exec("ulimit -a");
            in = p.getInputStream();
            isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
            br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            System.out.println("Result of p = runTime.exec(\"ulimit -a\");");
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
            }
            p.waitFor();
    }
```

Comment: Add the absolute path to ulimit to make sure you are executing the correct one, e.g. /bin/uname

Answer (score 0):

bash executes a ulimit command of its own? Check .profile, .bashrc, etc.

Comment: or on enterprise level systems, /etc/profile, possibly  /var/etc/profile.local .  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`ulimit` is a shell builtin and its default values are based on the configuration of the shell. It's possible that Java's using a default shell other than bash. Even if that's not the case, it could be that you have some settings in, for example, `.profile` that are invoked when you've got a command line but not when running the shell programmatically.

Comment: Java doesn't exec via a shell at all unless you tell it to, so there must be a ulimit program as well.

Comment: There is no ulimit program on my machine.